# pthread_setname_np failed, errno is 2

Tags: linux, multithreading

I want to set my thread name, and I check my linux glibc verison is 2.12, include the pthread_setname_np API, but i got errno 2 when execute pthread_setname_np, I found 2 is ENOENT,meant to "No such file or directory". I don't understand. but I found in my same code, pthread_setname_np return success in another linux system.
**the version info of return success:**

*root@Gzpeak:/home/wzx/thread# uname -a  

Linux Gzpeak 3.13.0-86-generic #130-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:27:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  
 
root@Gzpeak:/home/wzx/thread# cat /proc/version  
 
Linux version 3.13.0-86-generic (buildd@lgw01-19) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #130-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:27:15 UTC 2016  

root@Gzpeak:/home/wzx/thread# getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION  

glibc 2.19*
**the version info of return error:**
*[root@localhost wzx]#uname -a*
*Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@localhost wzx]# cat /proc/version

Linux version 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-008.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012

[root@localhost wzx]# getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION
glibc 2.12*
please someone tell me, tank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in [proc5](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) page, the "`/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/comm`" file exists only since linux 2.6.33. the second linux version is 2.6.32, so pthread_setname_np return error although glibc is v2.12. BTW, @galka thank you for your advice, give me a way to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't or failed to start a thread or it had been already finished.

> pthread_setname_np fails to open /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm, then the call may fail with one of the errors described in open(2)
>
> The system may reuse a thread ID after a terminated thread has been joined, or a detached thread has terminated. POSIX says: "If an application attempts to use a thread ID whose lifetime has ended, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: I found my code worked in another linux system, and i gave two of them version information in my question, can you give me more advice?

Comment: So you are saying you get success on  newer kernel and glibc. Man page says glibc 2.12. There is a sample program in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html. Did you run it on your second Linux? If it does not fail you did smth wrong in your program, if it does you have a different story. Without taking a look at your code I may suggest: try debugging your program: with strace -fp, gdb, do some printfs before and after you start thread, finish thread, change name, add some sleep()s to thread, make sure it alive when you change its name on 'not lucky' Linux system.

Comment: I found the answer as you advised, the second linux version is 2.6.32, and "/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/com" file only exists since 2.6.33. thank you for your advice.